# What is the drawback for using Strings for non-String specific data?

Tags: java, types

I know this might be a kind of "silly" question. I have created software applications before where I initialized basically all of my variables as strings, and saved them in my database as VARCHARs. Then, I would gather them from the database and convert them as needed. Is there any reason this is not an efficient method for initializing variables and saving them in my database?

I know that for extremely large applications, this can cause an issue with computing time, because I am unnecessarily converting variables that could have been initialized as the appropriate type to begin with. But, for smaller applications, is this "okay" to do?

Comment: Is there a reason *to* do it?

Comment: "_Excessively stringly typed code is usually a pain to understand and detonates at runtime with errors that the compiler would normally find._" [c2](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StringlyTyped)

Comment: I've done it before, but this was because I had to create a list of commands for an app I made. So the user had to input string ofc, then I will use regex to make sure the input is in the correct format depending on the type of command being queried. So in this case, I actually needed to use string, but then convert each token to it's actual type and call the command the user needed to call in the first place

Comment: This is a question that has some potential, but right now it's worded entirely too broadly.  I would say that discussing whether or not it's "okay" to do this may not be the entire problem; you're wondering about database modeling and storing the right type of data into your database.  I'll reword the title a bit, but I'd like you to sort out parts of the body of the question.

Comment: Ths is likely to generate an entirely unnecessary mess. You lose most of the power and flexibility of both your programming language and your database. Why would you want to do things this way?

Comment: immibis and Hobo Sapiens, I don't necessarily WANT to do it, per se, but I don't always know what I might need to convert to in the future. For example, I take a lot of information from the users in textfields, which then requires me to convert the values to other types, based on what I need. For example, a textfield that asks for an item price will require me to convert the price to a double. Smac89, thank you for the input. Makoto, I didn't know exactly how to word it, so that's why I quoted "okay".

Comment: You said "I don't always know what I might need to convert to in the future" - you should type the data fields in the database appropriately, meaning that the type of data you put in is the type of database field. Upon reading from the DB, when you need to convert to something, it's still possible (if not even easier) if you've used appropriate types instead of strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Some reasons to use proper types

**1. Least surprise.** If developers are going to grab numerical data from your database, they would find it weird that you're storing them as strings.

**2. Developer convenience.** Another is the nuisance of having to parse the data into the correct type every time. If you just store it as the correct type, then you would save people the trouble of having to put

```
int age = 0;
try {
  age = Integer.parseInt(ageStr);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

all over the code.

**3. Data quality.** The code example above hints at a third problem. Now it's possible for somebody to store "no_age" or "foo" or something in the column, which is a data quality issue. The best way to deal with errors is to make them impossible in the first place.

**4. Storage efficiency.** Storage efficiency is a factor as well. Different types have different ways of encoding data, and strings are not an efficient way to store numbers, bits, etc.

**5. Network efficiency.** If you store data in wasteful formats, then that often translates to unnecessary network utilization. This is why binary formats are generally more efficient than text formats like JSON or XML. But web services don't typically treat network efficiency as the *driving* engineering concern.

**6. Processing efficiency.** If the data is inherently numeric, then forcing everybody to parse it incurs processing cost.

**7. Different types support different rules.** In his answer, Hightower makes the good point that different types have special rules for ordering, which impacts ranges and sorts. I like this point because it impacts actual program behavior, whereas the concerns I mention above might be more academic for small apps with a single developer.

### An example illustrating the efficiency benefit

Suppose you want to store eight bits. If you were to store that as a string you might have "TFFTFFTF", which under UTF-8 and ASCII would take 64 bits (8 chars x 8 bits per char) to store eight bits of actual information. Relatively speaking that's a big difference.

Incidentally, even if your data is numeric, it's not good to just use `BIGINT`, for example. The different types of integer in a database have different storage requirements and so you should think about the number of bits you actually need, use unsigned representations if appropriate (no reason to waste a sign bit on numbers that can't be negative), etc. Wrong choices tend to add up quickly as you create new foreign keys that have to be BIGINTs now, new rows that all have a bunch of BIGINTs, etc. Your storage and backup requirements end up being needlessly demanding.

### So. Is it "OK" to use strings?

These efficiency concerns may not matter at all for something small, which is what you were asking. Or there may be reasons to prefer an inefficient format over one that's more efficient, as my JSON/XML example above suggests. So as far as whether it's "OK", I can't answer that, but hopefully the considerations above give you some tools to make that decision yourself.

Still I'd try to get into the habit of using the right type, and I certainly wouldn't go out of my way to store things as strings without some reason. In bitset cases I could see potentially avoiding having to deal with bit manipulation, which can be tricky til you get the hang of it. (But some databases have special bitset types.) You mention not knowing the type and maybe that's a plausible reason in some cases, though I would lean more on refactoring here.

Comment: you have made some excellent points in your answer. I appreciate the effort that you have put forth in answering my silly, but truly pondered-upon question. Thanks again for the response.

Answer (score 1):

There are some reasons. For examples, think about searching for a **time range**. This is easy to find using datetime fields. But not easy with strings, because you have to do it at your application.

Other point is **sorting** on a varchar will be different to a int type field. At varchar 10 is before 2, but at int it comes after that.

Comment: Nice example illustrating a behavioral consequence of using incorrect types.

Comment: Yes, very nice example. Thank you for that.